# return maybe value when referencing key-value list

Tags: haskell

I use key-value lists in haskell and I would like to get the value Nothing when the key is not found in the list instead of the exception. For example:

```
*> x
fromList [(1,[(6,14.0),(3,9.0),(2,7.0)]),(2,[(4,15.0),(3,10.0)]),(3,[(6,2.0),(4,11.0)]),(5,[(4,6.0)]),(6,[(5,9.0)])]
*> x ! 7
*** Exception: Map.find: element not in the map
```

is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LMHTFY: [`Map k a -> k -> Maybe a`](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=Map+k+a+-%3E+k+-%3E+Maybe+a).

The very first result is [`Map.lookup`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/containers/latest/doc/html/Data-Map-Lazy.html#v%3alookup), which is what you want.

Comment: Or `flip lookup`. I never understood the coice of argument order in `Data.Map`.

Comment: @DanielFischer Argument order is more or less a wash for `lookup`. But for operations that modify a map, the current order is clearly better. It lets you compose multiple operations on a map with just function composition.

Comment: @Carl I disagree. The argument order for `insert` is clearly suboptimal. Every time one builds a `Map`, one has to write the clumsy `foldl' (flip . uncurry $ insertWith' (+))`. Blech.

Comment: @DanielFischer In the large amount of `Map` using code I've written, I've never done anything even slightly like that. I guess I just don't have that use case.

Comment: @Carl Apparently you don't have that use case. But whenever you update a `Map` with a long list of key/value pairs, a (strict) left fold is a must. And that occurs more often than not when I use `Map`s.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Isn't that what `fromListWith` is for? I suppose that doesn't help with bulk inserts, though you could use `unionWith` as well. The better question would be why there aren't bulk insert functions to begin with, since that seems like a common use case.

Comment: @C.A.McCann `fromListWith` would probably now be okay for the initial `Map` with `Data.Map.Strict`. It (often) wasn't usable before that because the combining function's result wasn't forced. But when you update an existing `Map`, that isn't an option. For an associative combining function (common case), you could `fromListWith` the new stuff and then `unionWith`, but again, before `Data.Map.Strict` that used to create thunks. Now you can do that, maybe that would even be more efficient than `foldl'`, gotta test when I have a case for it again (old dog, new tricks, you know).

Comment: @DanielFischer: Ah, I don't think I ever tried to use a `Map` where strictness concerns would be significant; that aside I would expect `fromListWith` and `unionWith` to be quite reasonably efficient. Still seems like there ought to be `inserts` and `insertsWith` functions, by analogy with `unions` and `unionsWith`.